# Is it plausible that the word "bellua"(beast) derived from "bellum"(war)? (or vice versa)

Tags: etymology

I saw Luis Vives [made the claim](https://books.google.com/books?id=8RREBgAAQBAJ&pg=PR147&lpg=PR147&dq=Truly%20fighting%20belongs%20neither%20to%20good%20men%20nor%20to%20thieves&source=bl&ots=1mfNFI17ZG&sig=ACfU3U3Q6qUFnDUzBXo2M6S1Q2TwBN1nSA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiNsbK_oLnsAhUZiFwKHQlIDAEQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=Truly%20fighting%20belongs%20neither%20to%20good%20men%20nor%20to%20thieves&f=false) that "bellum" is derived *from* "bellua":

> Truly fighting belongs neither to good men nor to thieves, nor to any that are men at all, but is a right bestial fury and therefore it was named *Bellum* from *bellua* a beast.

Erasmus, his friend, [mentions](https://books.google.com/books?id=J_P8xVdZzKsC&pg=PA405&lpg=PA405&dq=Other%20grammarians%20prefer%20to%20think%20it%20is%20derived%20from%20bellua%20%27beast%27&source=bl&ots=5I6Nv2NC3G&sig=ACfU3U3p6jTdDJ-gGm2P9PhPFUVupzfAiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHn_rLobnsAhXFDuwKHSfuCNwQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=Other%20grammarians%20prefer%20to%20think%20it%20is%20derived%20from%20bellua%20%27beast%27&f=false) "grammarians" who think so (though he himself does not share this view).

Other [sources](https://books.google.com/books?id=R6hWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=it%20was%20named%20*Bellum*%20from%20*bellua*%20a%20beast&source=bl&ots=1UsJmbsa3l&sig=ACfU3U3VMjjsmY4VFm_I87UUqz7zLYUTBQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjL2er4nrnsAhUkNOwKHaOdC-sQ6AEwAXoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=it%20was%20named%20*Bellum*%20from%20*bellua*%20a%20beast&f=false) prefer the other direction. (i.e *bellua* from *bellum*).

Yet, I could not find any modern source that suggests this relation. Based on our knowledge today, can we rule this supposition out with high degree of certainty?

Comment: related https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/7595/39

Comment: another related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6558/81

Comment: It is  bēlua, not "bellua".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Michiel de Vaan, in his 2008 *Etymological Dictionary of Latin and the other Italic Languages*, doesn't even mention a possible connection, so it's safe to say a link isn't considered plausible in either connection by modern etymologists.

For *bēlua* he notes that some have been prompted by the similarity in meaning to *bēstia* to posit a preform **bēslVwa* for both, and that since words for 'animal' can be derived from 'to breathe' (cf. Gm. **diusa-* 'animal' < PIE **dʰus-* 'to breathe'), some have proposed *bēlua* < PIE **dʰwes-lo-*, but this is problematic as initial **dʰw-* should have yielded Latin *f-*, as was already noted by Pokorny in 1959. Meiser explains the *b-* as a consequence of word-internal sandhi, but nothing points to the word having been part of a compound. De Vaan's ultimate conclusion is that the etymologies of *bēlua* and *bēstia* are uncertain.

As for *bellum*, it's well-known that the older form was the disyllabic *duellum*, and De Vaan follows Pinault 1987 in positing a diminutive **duenelo-* of *bonus* < Very Old Latin *duenos*, with its semantic development from 'quite good, quite brave' into 'action of valour, war' being understood as euphemism. Also perhaps notable here is that the change *dwe-* > *bo-* may require that the following *l* be an *l exilis*, which is the case in *duellum* (geminated *l* is always *l exilis*), but not in *bēlua*, which has an *l pinguis* (but also, as you note, a variant form *bēllua*, so...); it may not.

So, conclusion: there are still unanswered questions when it comes to the etymologies of all of these words, but *bēlua* and *bellum* sharing a common origin or being derived one from the other isn't even on the radar anymore.